# How to auto text wrap on Raphael print method's output?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael, snap.svg

I am just looking for a way to auto wrap text when using the Raphael's print method.
I have some code that helps in a way for the text method to line break based on sub-strings in an array and works ok :

```
var t1 = paper.text({text:
      ["Life", "is great", "but it is ", "limited!"]
      , fill:"black", fontSize:"18px"}).selectAll("tspan").forEach(function(tspan, j){
         tspan.attr({x:0, y:25*(j+1)});
      });
```

I was wondering if any one has any ideas on how to do this on the print method?
someone has suggested the following long time ago(2010 I guess):

"why not split the string into multiple strings, and
print() each one successively with an increasing Y offset
from the start point of your first line?"

How to implement this please?  Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

@ crockz, I actually want to use this code on snap.svg. I realized that Snap doesn't have the support for `\n`. How can I replace `\n` on your code to make it work on snap svg as well please?! Any ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a possible solution is to make a "test print" with paper.text and then insert line breaks where it's needed, you would have to use the exact same font.

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0,500,500);
var phrase = "Etiam porttitor risus in ex blandit sodales. Ut cursus mi augue, sit amet interdum diam interdum sit amet. Nunc nec lectus ex. Nulla facilisi. In non sollicitudin elit. Pellentesque finibus suscipit venenatis. In in nibh consequat, mollis ligula quis, dictum sapien. Nullam dapibus nunc eu odio laoreet laoreet. Suspendisse rutrum purus nibh, ac dignissim eros ultricies id. Curabitur ornare pellentesque ligula, eu sodales augue commodo in. Donec tincidunt hendrerit sapien quis dapibus.";
var textBoxWidth = 300;
var words = phrase.split(" ");
var newPhrase = words[0];
var t1 = paper.text(10,50,newPhrase)
  .attr({
    fill: "none",
    stroke:"none",
    "text-anchor":"start",
    "font-size":"18px",
    "font-family":"Arial"});
for(i=1;i<words.length;i++){
    t1.attr({"text":newPhrase + " " + words[i]});
    if(t1.getBBox().width<=textBoxWidth){
        newPhrase += " " + words[i];
    } else {
        newPhrase += "\n" + words[i];
    }
}
var t2 = paper.print(10, 50, newPhrase, paper.getFont("Arial"), 18).attr({fill: "#000"});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/bbg4go9q/

UPDATE:

Just put every line inside an array and then go through each one of them.

http://jsfiddle.net/crockz/bbg4go9q/1/

Comment: @ crockz, I actually want to use this code on snap.svg. I realized that Snap doesn't have the support for \n. How can I replace \n on the above code to make it work on snap svg as well please?! Any ideas!